# Clock algorithm lags behind a few minutes after a while

Tags: arduino, clock

I'm trying to make a digital clock with Arduino but after a few hours it's behind a few minutes.

I increased aux value after 4ms so technically after 15000*4 ms it should increase the last minute digit right?

```cpp
void loop() {
  // t is first hour digit
  // y is the second hour digit
  // u is the first minute digit
  // i is the second minute digit

  if (t == 2 && y == 4) {
    t = 0;
    y = 0;
  }
  digitalWrite(ox, 0);
  digitalWrite(oy, 1);
  digitalWrite(mx, 1);
  digitalWrite(my, 1);
  draw(t);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(ox, 1);
  digitalWrite(oy, 0);
  digitalWrite(mx, 1);
  digitalWrite(my, 1);
  draw(y);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(ox, 1);
  digitalWrite(oy, 1);
  digitalWrite(mx, 0);
  digitalWrite(my, 1);
  draw(u);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(ox, 1);
  digitalWrite(oy, 1);
  digitalWrite(mx, 1);
  digitalWrite(my, 0);
  draw(i);
  delay(1);
  aux++;
  if (aux == 15000) {
    aux = 0;
    i++;
  }
  if (i > 9) {
    i = 0;
    u++;

  }
  if (u == 6) {
    u = 0;
    y++;
  }
  if (y > 9) {
    y = 0;
    t++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot rely on JavaScript to keep accurate time. Instead use a library like moment.js.

Comment: moment.js is still JS, it can't keep it any more accurately. It is just referencing the system time instead, which is what you have to do if you want accurate time.

Comment: This is obviously Arduino code (which is C++) and not JavaScript. Why was a JavaScript answer accepted?

Comment: If you want accurate time, you will need a RTC module.

Comment: Or is this Processing code (Java)?

Comment: @gre_gor Because clock stuff is clock stuff, regardless of language. It's a basic system level thing. JavaScript was used to explain, so what I'm talking about can be seen right from the question. It doesn't matter what language it is, they all have the same limitations.

Comment: Also, to note, the question was originally tagged with JS, hence some of the JS talk.

Comment: @gre_gor yes i'm sorry my mistake. But he still explained me why it doesn't work and what i need to do to fix it

Answer (score -2):

The problem with trying to do clocks like this is you can't guarantee that your code is running at precisely the time you want.

As a simple example, consider the `setTimeout()` function available in browsers. If I tell `setTimeout()` to run my function every 1000ms, I would expect that the different between each call to be exactly 1000ms:

```js
let lastTime;

const run = () => {
  const now = Date.now();
  lastTime && console.log('diff', now - lastTime);
  lastTime = now;
  setTimeout(run, 1000);
}

run();
```

Notice however, that this isn't the case. At least not on my computer. Sometimes it's difference will be exactly 1000ms, other times it'll be `1004`, `1008`, `996`, etc. Very, very close. We're talking differences of about 1/200th of a blink, but, when you are trying to keep time, those tiny amounts of time add up.

Here I'll try to track time based on what I think the offset should be:

```js
let lastTime;
let currentTime = Date.now();
const interval = 1000;

const pad = (num, len = 2) => ('000' + num).slice(-len);
const format = d => pad(d.getHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds()) + '.' + pad(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);

const run = () => {
  const now = Date.now();
  console.log(
    'tracked time:', format(new Date(currentTime)),
    '|',
    'offset:', Date.now() - currentTime, 
    '|', 
    lastTime ? 'since last: ' + (now - lastTime) : 'first run');
  lastTime = now;
  currentTime += interval;
  setTimeout(run, interval);
};

run();
```

You can see that very quickly we start drifting away (compare with the timestamp SO includes in the console message on the right). With this, you can imagine how after a couple of hours, you're off by a couple of minutes.

The trick for having a clock is you'll really need to rely on the system clock. Pretty much every computer ever has some sort of clock mechanism which it uses to keep really precise time. That's why your computer clock doesn't drift like the one kept purely in software.

Instead of just incrementing based on waits, you'll have to actually just grab the real time from the system. You won't be able to maintain it without referencing it in some way or form.

Comment: Is it possible in this case the `setInterval` method approach will be more accurate than the `setTimeout` approach? I think, the `setInterval` is less dependent on calculation delay.

Comment: Nope. They're both pretty much identical. Any calculation delay (at least in this example) would be on the scale of nanoseconds, not milliseconds. It's possible in other more complex scenarios, but even then, if one isn't done and another runs, it's actually going to get even more slow because it'll start chewing up more memory.

Comment: The question is about Arduino (C++) or Processing (Java) not JavaScript.

Comment: The language is irrelevant. All timing stuff works the same, regardless of language. I used JS because it could actually be run from the browser, making for a better hands-on demo.

Comment: Arduino doesn't have a system clock. It has `millis()` (milliseconds after boot), which isn't accurate enough for proper timekeeping.

Comment: Which means you'd need to add some module that provides a system clock. However, that doesn't change the gist of my answer: you can't do it in software, you need a clock.

Comment: "Anecdotal experience has reported the drift in timing accuracy can be around three or four seconds per twenty-four hour period."